# plotly express legend not responsive to any attempt at adjustment (including complete removal)

Tags: visualization, legend, plotly-python

I am doing a visualization for a paper im writing about differences in specific stances between men and women.

In order to do this, i want to create a plotly figure with 4 subplots. This worked great, but  there is one problem - the legend.
The visualization turns out like this:
[image]

The legend overlaps the y axis, and i want to move it a bit to the right,
but i can't manage to alter it or even remove it.
Nothing seems to work - i tried to use fig.update_layout() but that didnt work, i tried to do trace.update() but that didn't work aswell.
Well, it did work - when i printed the traces it showed me that in the parameter "showlegend" it was "False", and yet the legend ignores it and still shows up!

please help me figure out how to move the legend a bit, or even remove it completely.

this is my code:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, horizontal_spacing=0.01, vertical_spacing=0.01, 
                     subplot_titles= ('Male','Female'), x_title= 'Average Stance Score', y_title= "Interest in % of Tweets")
                     
gender = ['Male', 'Female']
status = ['Married', 'Unmarried']

for gender_index, gender in enumerate(gender, start=1):
    for status_index, status in enumerate(status, start = 1):

        # Filter data
        gender_data = user_stats_merged[user_stats_merged['gender'] == gender]
        status_data = gender_data[gender_data['status'] == status]

        # Create subplot
        fig_gender_status = px.scatter(status_data, x= 'mean_stance', y = 'interest', color = 'mean_stance' )
        

        
        if party == 'Female':
            if body == 'Married': 
            # Fit axes
                
                fig.update_xaxes(range=[-1.1, 1.1], row=status_index, col=gender_index, showgrid = False, zeroline = False, visible = False)
                fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 1.02], row=status_index, col=gender_index, title_text =  "Married", side = 'right',
                                  showgrid = False, zeroline = False, nticks = 2)
            elif body == 'Unmarried': 
                fig.update_xaxes(range=[-1.1, 1.1], row=status_index, col=gender_index, showgrid = False, zeroline = False)
                fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 1.02], row=status_index, col=gender_index, title_text =  "Unmarried", side = 'right',
                                  showgrid = False, zeroline = False, nticks = 2)
                
        elif party == 'Male': 
            if body == 'Married': 
                fig.update_xaxes(range=[-1.1, 1.1], row=status_index, col=gender_index, showgrid = False, zeroline = False, visible = False)
                fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 1.02], row=status_index, col=gender_index,  showgrid = False, zeroline = False) 

            
            elif body == 'Unmarried':
                fig.update_xaxes(range=[-1.1, 1.1], row=status_index, col=gender_index,  showgrid = False, zeroline = False) 
                fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 1.02], row=status_index, col=gender_index,  showgrid = False, zeroline = False) 
        
        # Update figure
        for trace in fig_gender_status['data']:
            fig.add_trace(trace, row=status_index, col=gender_index)


fig.update_layout(
    width=1000,  
    height=800, 
    # Change colorscale into red, gray and blue
    coloraxis_colorscale=[[0.0, "#E70E02"],  [0.5, 'rgb(160, 160, 160)'], [1.0, "#3663AD" ]],
    # Fit title to plot
    title={'text': 'Average Stance vs. Interest','font_size': 20 ,"x": 0.5},
    # Fiddle with margins to make it look better
    margin=dict(l=100, r=100, t=80, b=60),
    plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(240,240,240)' ,
    ) 
    

fig.show()
```